# How can i make this recursive javascript output to anything other than the console

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorization

This is inspired by Project Euler Q3. So you have all seen it before. If you haven't seen it, --> https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

I am not after the solution to the question.

Recursion is still very new to me.  I slapped together this code, it gives me the correct solution (well, it gives me the correct factors), however, i can only manage to get it to output to the console, whereas i would like to get it to return a value of some sort that could used elsewhere, perhaps for a sort or a max/min sort of thing.  I was thinking perhaps an array with the factors in it.  As it stands now though, i understand that whenever i have initialized an array inside of the function, it gets reinitialized with each recursive call to the function. So that hasn't worked.

```
function primefy(n) {
    var isPrime = true;
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if(n % i === 0){
            isPrime = false;
            console.log(i);
            primefy(n/i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime){
        console.log(n);
    }
}

primefy(prompt("A number please?"));
```

if i feed it 8 it will log 2 2 2, 18 yields 2 3 3 and so on.  The math seems to be correct, but clearly the implementation is off.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t1t64scx/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Post it as an answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - with an explaination

Answer (score 3):

To return a value from a recursive process (rather than simply performing some actions along the way), each instance of the function needs to return something up to the instance that called it (or out to the original caller, if it's the root instance). To do that, it needs to combine its local results with the results passed up to it by its children.

For instance:

```
function primeFactors(n) {
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if(n % i === 0){
            return [i].concat(primeFactors(n/i));
        }
    }
    return [n];
}
```

Note that we no longer need `isPrime` or the `break`, because we're going to `return` as early as possible. By the time we get back to the root, we've built up an array containing all of the factors we found. I've renamed the function to better reflect what it's actually returning, but that's personal taste.

(Incidentally, you don't need to loop all the way to `n`; you're guaranteed to never find a factor between `Math.sqrt(n)` and `n` inside of that loop.)

Comment: Thank you for that @S Mc Crohan.  I reworked it this morning to where i could at least get a nested array to return. But your solution is still much lovelier.